# Iterating over a .txt file with a regular expression conditional

Tags: python, regex, loops, conditional-statements, matching

Program workflow:

1. Open  "asigra_backup.txt" file and read each line
2. Search for the exact string: "Errors: " + {any value ranging from 1 - 100}. e.g "Errors: 12"
3. When a match is found, open a separate .txt file in write&append mode
4. Write the match found. Example: "Errors: 4"
5. In addition to above write, append the next 4 lines below the match found in step 3; as that is additional log information
   What I've done:
6. Tested a regular expressions that matches with my sample data on regex101.com
7. Used list comprehension to find all matches in my test file
   Where I need help (please):
8. Figuring out how to append additional 4 lines of log information below each match string found

CURRENT CODE:

```
result = [line.split("\n")[0] for line in open('asigra_backup.txt') if re.match('^Errors:\s([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|100)',line)]

print(result)
```

CURRENT OUTPUT:

```
['Errors: 1', 'Errors: 128']
```

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
Errors: 1
Pasta
Fish 
Dog
Doctonr
Errors: 128
Lemon
Seasoned
Rhinon
Goat
```

SAMPLE .TXT FILE

```
Errors: 1
Pasta
Fish 
Dog
Doctonr
Errors: 128
Lemon
Seasoned
Rhinon
Goat
Errors: 0 
Rhinon
Cat 
Dog
Fish
```

Comment: You're not doing anything like what the workflow says.

Comment: Try implementing the workflow with a `for line in file:` loop, not a list comprehension. When you want to get the next 4 lines, you can do `for _ in range(4): nextline = file.readline()`

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer this question without doing the assignment for you. It seems like you didn't really attempt to do it yourself, you just started it and hoped someone would finish it for you.

Answer (score 1):

For those wanting additional clarification, as it may help the next person, this was my final solution:

```
def errors_to_file(self):
    """
    Opens file containing Asigra backup logs, "asigra_backup.txt",  and returns a list of all errors within the log.
    Uses a regular expression match conditional on each line within the asigra backup log file. Error number range is 1 - 100.
    Formats errors log by appending a space every 10th element in the errors log list.txt
    Writes formatted error log to a file in current directory: "asigra_errors.txt"
    """

    # "asigra_backup.txt" contains log information from the performed backup. 
    with open('asigra_backup.txt', "r") as f:


        lines0 = [line.rstrip() for line in f]  

        # empty list that is appended with errors found in the log
        lines = []

        for i, line in enumerate(lines0):


            if re.match('^Errors:\s([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|100)',line):  
                lines.extend(lines0[i:i+9]) 
              

    
    if len(lines) == 0: 
        print("No errors found")
        print("Gracefully exiting")
        sys.exit(1)

    k = ''
    N = 9

    formatted_errors = list(chain(*[lines[i : i+N] + [k] 
                if len(lines[i : i+N]) == N 
                else lines[i : i+N] 
                for i in range(0, len(lines), N)]))


    with open("asigra_errors.txt", "w") as e:

        for i, line in enumerate(formatted_errors): 
            e.write(f"{line}\n")
```

Huge thank you to those that answered my question.

Comment: Project repository: https://github.com/ZimCanIT/Python_Projects/tree/main/filtering_logs_with_regular_expressions

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @ZimCanIT if your issue is resolved then I would enourage you to mark this as an accepted answer. You'll have to click the grey check mark below the voting buttons to do so. This acts as a pointer for future readers to jump to the relevant answer quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Using better regex and `re.findall` can make it easier. In the following regex, all `Errors:`  and 4 following lines are detected.

```
import re
regex_matches = re.findall('(?:[\r\n]+|^)((Errors:\s*([1-9][0-9]?|100))(?:[\r\n\s\t]+.*){4})', open('asigra_backup.txt', 'r').read())
open('separate.txt', 'a').write('\n' + '\n'.join([i[0] for i in regex_matches]))
```

To access error numbers or error lines following lines can use:

```
error_rows = [i[1] for i in regex_matches]
error_numbers = [i[2] for i in regex_matches]
print(error_rows)
print(error_numbers)
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a code which prints the output as requested. The code will work when `Errors: 1` line is added as last line. See the text I have parsed:

```
data_to_parse = """
Errors: 56
Pasta
Fish 
Dog
Doctonr
Errors: 0
Lemon
Seasoned
Rhinon
Goat
Errors: 45
Rhinon
Cat 
Dog
Fish
Errors: 34
Rhinon
Cat 
Dog
Fish1
Errors: 1
"""
```

See the code which gives the desired output without using regex. Indices have been used to get desired data.

```
lines = data_to_parse.splitlines()

errors_indices = []

i = 0
k = 0

for line in lines: # where Errors: are located are found in saved in list errors_indices. 
    if 'Errors:' in line:
        errors_indices.append(i)
    i = i+1

#counter = False

while k < len(errors_indices):
    counter = False # It is needed to find the indices when Errors: 0 is hit. 
    for j in range(errors_indices[k-1], errors_indices[k]):
        if 'Errors:' in lines[j]:
            lines2 = lines[j].split(':')
            lines2_val = lines2[1].strip()
            if int(lines2_val) != 0:
                print(lines[j])
            if int(lines2_val) == 0:
                counter = True
            
        elif 'Errors:' not in lines[j] and counter == False:
            print(lines[j])
    k=k+1
```

I have tried a few times to see if the code is working properly. It looks it gives the requested output properly. See the output when the code is run as:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Baris, I ended up with a different solution, shown below. I like the fact that you did not make use of a regular expression as that can be tricky to debug when there are variations in the output log file.